# Problems with casting LinQ result to strongly typed collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, casting

I guess this is trivial but not for me.

I have a collection `MembershipUserCollection`. I wanted to perform some Linq query over it so I've used `OfType<MembershipUser>()` method and then applied `Where()` on it. However, I do not know how to cast back my results to `MembershipUserCollection`?

This is my code:

```
MembershipUserCollection Users;
Users = GetAllUsers(pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords).OfType<MembershipUser>().Where(user => user.Email == emailToMatch); //how to cast it back to MembershipUserCollection ?
```

`GetAllUsers(pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords)` is returning `MembershipUserCollection`

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible solutions:

```
   var users = GetAllUsers(pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords)
      .OfType<MembershipUser>()
      .Where(user => user.Email == emailToMatch);

   MembershipUserCollection membershipUsers = new MembershipUserCollection();
   users
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(membershipUsers.Add);
```

Another one with foreach statement:

```
foreach (var user in users)
{
    membershipUsers.Add(user);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it in the query itself, but you should be able to do this:

```
var query = GetAllUsers(pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords)
                .OfType<MembershipUser>()
                .Where(user => user.Email == emailToMatch);

var users = new MembershipUserCollection();
foreach (var user in query)
{
    users.Add(user);
}
```

(And, of course, you could wrap that logic up into an extension method if you wanted and then call the extension method in the query.)

Comment: Thanks, Compiler says that there is an explict cast.

Answer (score 0):

So it was trivial, I just had to cast it like this:

```
MembershipUserCollection Users;
Users = (MembershipUserCollection)GetAllUsers(pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords).OfType<MembershipUser>().Where(user => user.Email == emailToMatch).Cast<MembershipUser>();
```

Thanks guys for your asnwers.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. VS IDE accepted this but during compilation it returned error.